# limit TextView to certain number of lines in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I need to restrict my textview to only 6 lines. How do I limit my textview to 6 lines? I have put some character limit of 50 characters anyways.

Comment: 50 characters is probably too small for 6 lines for any device. Assuming it's an iPhone or iPad. Resize it so that fits only 50 characters.

Comment: that can be changed any time. i have kept it for time being. my main concern is of number of lines. at this moment if i enter one character per line it goes to 50 lines. i dont need that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is rarely simple to achieve. Try out following code

```
inputTextView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 6
inputTextView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
```

Comment: Thank you. u solved my query but the problem what i still have is that if i press enter after 6 lines though it wont show it is accepting and the cursor disappears. i get it once i press backspace i.e if i press enter 4 times after 6 lines i need to press backspace 4 times to get the cursor. Hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

for swift 4 this one worked for without any bugs:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let existingLines = textView.text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
    let newLines = text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
    let linesAfterChange = existingLines.count + newLines.count - 1
    return linesAfterChange <= textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines
}
```

and if you want to limit characters also:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let existingLines = textView.text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
        let newLines = text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
        let linesAfterChange = existingLines.count + newLines.count - 1
        if(text == "\n") {
            return linesAfterChange <= textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines
        }

        let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
        let numberOfChars = newText.count
        return numberOfChars <= 30 // 30 characters limit
    }
}
```

don't forget to add how many lines you want the limit to be in `viewDidLoad`:

```
txtView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2
```